# why pid of child and its process are different?

Tags: c++, process, pid

Here my code:

```
extern int errno;
pid_t system1(const char * command)
{
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();
    cout<<"PID in child "<<(int)pid<<endl;
    if (pid < 0) {
        return pid;
    } else if (pid == 0) {
        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, (char*)NULL);
        _exit(1);
    }

    int stat_val;
    pid_t child_pid;
    cout << "Hello1" << endl;
    child_pid = wait(&stat_val);
    cout << "child_pid = " <<(int)child_pid<< endl;//LINE 1
    if(WIFEXITED(stat_val))
    printf("Child has terminated with exit code %d\n", WIFEXITED(stat_val));
    else
    printf("Child has existed abnormally\n");
    return child_pid;
}

int main( )
{ 
    int pid_1 = system1("setup.csh &");;
    struct stat status;
    sleep(10);
    cout<<"errno  = "<<errno<<endl;
    int i = kill(pid_1,0);
    cout<<"Pid id = "<<pid_1<<endl;
    cout<<"i === "<<i<<endl;
    cout<<"errno  = "<<errno<<endl;
    if(errno == ESRCH)
    {
        cout<<"process does not exist";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"process exist"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In above code I am getting different `PID` of child at `LINE 1` and `PID` of `process` `setup.csh` . Can anybody please help me out. I want to get `PID` of my `process` `setup.csh`.

I am looking other `PID` value using `ps -u user | grep setup.csh` in console.

Comment: This isn't clear.  You're seeing one value on `LINE_1`; what is the other value that you're seeing?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth using `ps -u | grep setup.csh` I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

When you run:

```
sh -c 'setup.csh &'
```

the original shell process forks another child process to run `csh`. The process hierarchy is:

```
YourProgram
    sh -c 'setup.csh &'
        csh setup.csh
```

There's no way to get this PID directly in the original program. Why don't you run `setup.csh` directly from your program, instead of going through the shell?

Actually, there's a way you can accomplish this. If you use the `exec` shell command, it runs the specified command in its own process, rather than forking a child:

```
system1('exec setup.csh &');
```

Comment: Is there any way I can get `PID` of process setup.csh and If run using `system()` then also I will not get PID.

Comment: No, you can't get it with `system()`, either. It works pretty much the same way as your `system1()` function. `setup.csh` is a grandchild process, you can only directly access child processes.

Comment: No, you can't do that. `execl` doesn't process shell syntax in the command. It won't split arguments, it doesn't understand `&`, etc.

Comment: @Balmar as you said run `system1('exec setup.csh &')` so what should I do with command pass to `system1`

Comment: That's intended to work with your existing definition of `system1`.